# find the maximum box width & length with the constraints

Tags: c

find the maximum of length & width of a box

there are four sides of a box, the cost per meter is 
2 width + 1 length is 2500
1 length is 1200
The accuracy of length and width should be down to 0.1 meter

the max width & and length both are 100 meters, the followings is my code, it should be wrong, the tutor ask me to use two for loops to find out the answer, but i don't have ideas... anyone can help?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dimension {
  float length; 
  float width;
};

    void findBox(float amount, struct dimension* dim) {

      /* Enter your code here */
      float i, j;
      float area = 0;
      float max_area = 1000;
      float cost = 0;

      float length=100;
      float width=100;
      cost = length * 2500 + (width * 2500 * 2) + length * 1200;

      while (cost > amount) {

        length -= 0.1;
        width -= 0.1;
        printf("%f",length);
        printf("%f",width);
        cost = length * 2500 + (width * 2500 * 2) + length * 1200;

        if (cost < amount) {
        printf("%f\n", length);
        printf ("%f\n", width);
        cost = length * 2500 + (width * 2500 * 2) + length * 1200;
        printf ("%f\n", cost);
        break;
        }

      }

    }

    int main() {
      struct dimension dim;
      findBox(20000, &dim);

    }
```

Comment: You need to reword your question a little (add some punctuation) as it's very hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do. imho of course :)

Comment: Why `float`? Unless you can answer that question convincingly ("because the tutor said so" *(\*)*) use `double`. *(\*) if the tutor said so, ask him/her "why `float`?"*

Comment: You need 2 loops because otherwise you will not test all possible combinations of `length` and `width`. With your code only square boxes are tested: you never calculate for a box of 80 x 33, for example.

Comment: @pmg
  for (length=0; length<=100; length+=0.1) {

    for (width=0; width<=100; width+=0.1) {
      area = length*width;
      cost = length*1200 + (length+width*2) * 2500;
      if( cost > amount  && area > max_area) {
     j = length;
  i = width;
  finalCost = cost;
  break;
  
   }
    }


  }

Comment: @pmg still have ideas :<

Comment: Ok, you have the two loops and calculate area and cost for every possible (length, width) pair. Then you must check if both are within limits, not if both are outside limits. Suggestion: add a `printf` inside the `if` just to see what is hapenning.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but based on what you've said I believe this is what your approach should look like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t length, width;
} box_t;

bool box_size_from_cost(uint32_t icost, box_t* obox) {
    if(icost > ((50 * 2500) + (50 * 1200)))
        return false;

    uint32_t width     = 0;
    uint32_t length[2] = { 0 };
    uint32_t cost[2]   = { 0 };

    for(; length[0] <= 1000; length[0]++, cost[0] += 120) {
        for(length[1] = length[0], cost[1] = cost[0]; width <= 1000; width += 2, length[1]++, cost[1] += 250) {
            if(cost[1] == icost) {
                if(obox != NULL) {
                    obox->width  = width;
                    obox->length = length[1];
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: box <cost>\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint32_t cost;
    if(sscanf(argv[1], "%"SCNu32, &cost) == EOF) {
        printf("Error: Invalid cost parameter.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    box_t box;
    if(!box_size_from_cost(cost, &box)) {
        printf("No box size costs %"PRIu32".\n", cost);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("A box of size %.1fx%.1f costs %"PRIu32".\n", (box.width * 0.1), (box.length * 0.1), cost);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```